# How to group percentage calculations on group by

Tags: sql, count, group-by, percentage

I have the following table with data:

mytable (country, gender):

```
+----------+----------+
| country  | gender   |
+----------+----------+
| China    | male     |
+----------+----------+
| China    | female   |
+----------+----------+
| China    | male     |
+----------+----------+
| China    | male     |
+----------+----------+
| Russia   | male     |
+----------+----------+
| Russia   | female   |
+----------+----------+
```

And I want a query select output like this:

```
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| country  | gender   | count  | percent   |
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| China    | male     |   3    |     75    |
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| China    | female   |   1    |     25    |
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| Russia   | male     |   1    |    50     |
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| Russia   | female   |   1    |    50     |
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

So basically I want calculate percentages for genders for each country.

How do I do this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: Yeah what DB he's using would be useful :) I'm on Oracle, and would use `RATIO_TO_REPORT` .. does that function exist on SqlServer or MySql ? Could help simplify the query if it does ;)

Comment: @Ditto first time i hear that function.

Comment: @Juan: probably doesn't exist then - I just posted an answer below, take the 2nd query - do you have SQLServer? or Mysql? I'd appreciate it if you could verify if that 2nd query works with RATIO_TO_REPORT :)  (or if it's a specifically Oracle function ... :) )

Comment: MySql doesn't support row_number/over/partition or any other analitical function.

Comment: I google it, looks like is for oracle only.

Comment: @juan: Cool, thanks. :(

Comment: I am looking for a cross RDBMS solution - which is not hard coded - and I've got it below :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as this:

```
select a.country, 
       a.gender, 
       (count(*) / b.qtd)*100 as percent
  from test a inner join
       (select country, count(*) qtd from test group by country) b
      on a.country = b.country
 group by a.country, a.gender
```

No need for two subqueries!
See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f41609/4

Comment: This one works and is simple, generic and cross RDBMS. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that @HenrikJuul-Nyholm Please consider in accepting the answer that you fell right if it is this one, please click on the V on the left side of this answer!

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66a621/2)**

```
SELECT g.country, 
        g.gender, 
        g.gender_count, 
        (g.gender_count * 1.0 / c.country_count) * 100
 FROM (
        SELECT country, gender, count(*) as gender_count
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY country, gender
      ) g
 JOIN (
        SELECT country, count(*) as country_count
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY country
      ) c
   ON g.country = c.country
```

Comment: With a few corrections this solution is just perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: tell me where I have a mistake and will fix it. btw you didnt say what is your db. We may found better solutions when not restrited to generic functions

Comment: At least MySQL is case sensitive to G != g, and it also needs "count(*) as country_count" and similar… But never mind, it works with those minor corrections :-) Btw, I was exactly looking for a cross platform RDBMS solution...

Comment: Fixed, also include a sqlfiddle. Please remember accept this answer if help you solve your problem

Comment: A little curious why you multiply with 1.0? To add some flexibility to some scenarios?

Comment: In some database you have to multiply with 1.0 to convert the int number to float and get correct division. Otherwise you get the decimal part truncate

Answer (score 0):

you could try this ..
(tested on Oracle 11):

```
  with w_data as (
        select 'China' country, 'male'  gender from dual union all
        select 'China'        , 'female'       from dual union all
        select 'China'        , 'male'         from dual union all
        select 'China'        , 'male'         from dual union all
        select 'Russia'       , 'male'         from dual union all
        select 'Russia'       , 'female'       from dual 
        ),
     w_sub as (
        select country, gender, count(*) ccount
          from w_data
         group by country, gender
        )
  select country, gender, ccount,
         ratio_to_report(ccount) over (partition by country)*100 percent
    from w_sub
  order by country, ccount desc
  /

  COUNTR GENDER     CCOUNT    PERCENT
  ------ ------ ---------- ----------
  China  male            3         75
  China  female          1         25
  Russia female          1         50
  Russia male            1         50
```

Avoiding the "WITH" clause (since I don't think that works on some Databases) ... assuming RATIO_TO_REPORT works ... 
same query written slightly differently:

```
  select country, gender, ccount,
         ratio_to_report(ccount) over (partition by country)*100 percent
    from (
           select country, gender, count(*) ccount
             from (
                    select 'China' country, 'male'  gender from dual union all
                    select 'China'        , 'female'       from dual union all
                    select 'China'        , 'male'         from dual union all
                    select 'China'        , 'male'         from dual union all
                    select 'Russia'       , 'male'         from dual union all
                    select 'Russia'       , 'female'       from dual 
                    )  w_data
            group by country, gender
           )
  order by country, ccount desc
  /
```

And finally, avoiding RATIO_TO_REPORT if you don't have it:

```
  select country, gender, ccount,
         (ccount / SUM(ccount) over (partition by country))*100 percent
    from (
           select country, gender, count(*) ccount
             from (
                    select 'China' country, 'male'  gender from dual union all
                    select 'China'        , 'female'       from dual union all
                    select 'China'        , 'male'         from dual union all
                    select 'China'        , 'male'         from dual union all
                    select 'Russia'       , 'male'         from dual union all
                    select 'Russia'       , 'female'       from dual 
                    )  w_data
            group by country, gender
           )
  order by country, ccount desc
  /
```

Comment: This solution is hard coding the value list of each column, and is very Oracle specific. Maybe fast, but not that elegant… Thx anyway..

Comment: @Henrick: The "hardcoding" of the value list is just a "placeholder" for your table .. it's meant to be replaced by your table .. ;)  The last option - if I understand correctly - will work fine on most other databases .. it is NOT Oracle specific ... (the first 1 definitely is ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Just group the countries and genders in the main query and get in a subquery how much genders there are for each group, applying the percentage formula.

```
select 
  a.country, 
  a.gender,
  count(a.gender) as `count`, 
  (
    select count(a.gender) / count(gender) * 100 
    from mytable 
    where country = a.country
  ) as percent
from mytable a 
group by 
  a.country, 
  a.gender
order by
  country,
  gender desc,
  percent desc
```

Comment: Sorry, this would be an elegant solution, but it doesnt give the result asked for… See output table in my question :-)

Comment: It is for sure the same result as the one you asked in your question, except that the rows appears in a different order. You asked in your question: "... I want calculate percentages for genders for each country". But I'm including an order by in the answer, or you can include the order you want when running it.

Comment: It doesnt work for me. It gives different percentages - at least when you add more data. The answer from @Jorge Campos works and is very similar.

Comment: could you show some data where the result doesn't match?

Comment: Actually, I really can't find any problem with my query... tried it with some other data and analysed it again and yet I'm unable to identify any problem. If possible, show me any data/result where it seems not to match.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, Have you found any data with wrong result? Let me know about it to adjust my answer...

Comment: I am not really qualified to tell you the difference between your solution and the solution by @Jorge Campos. I am working on a quite large dataset, which is difficult to post here. Thanks for your effort anyway :-)